# Fix element to bottom of screen

Tags: css, css-position

I have a textbox I want at the very bottom of the screen at all times. Using the following markup and css, I was able to get it close but there's a weird gap under it and it sits on top of other content.

Markup:

```
<div class="content">
 ... stuff here
</div>
<div class="message-text">
  <input type="text"  placeholder="Start typing to share a message">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message-text {
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0px;
 width:100%;
}
```

And here's a visual:

[image: Issue]

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: try `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` or maybe it is input's margin?

Comment: It actually was the padding on the input. Thanks a million!

Comment: Are you sure that it was `padding`, not `margin`?

Comment: Oh yeah. I set them both. It was indeed the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this property, it'll work.

```
.message-text {
 margin:0px;
}
```