# Adjust flex layout height for mobile device

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a layout that is similar to a console where there is a menu bar on top, an input line in the bottom, and in the middle there is a scrolling div with text that gets added as you type.

```js
let pre = $("pre")
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    pre.append("<span class='line'>line " + i + "</span>")
}
function bottom() {
    pre.scrollTop(pre.prop("scrollHeight"));
}
$("#commandline").on('keyup', function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13){
    pre.append("<span class='line'>" + $("#commandline").val() + "</span>");
    bottom();
    $("#commandline").val("");
  }
});
bottom();
```

```css
html, body {
  top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}


#container {
      position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#toprow, #bottomrow {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

#midrow {
  flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

pre {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

#commandline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="toprow">
        Menubar
      </div>
      <div id="midrow">
        <pre>
          <span>ton of lines</span>
        </pre>
      </div>
      <div  id="bottomrow">
        <input type="text" id="commandline">
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It all works fine in a normal browser. And it also renders fine in a mobile browser as long as you don't focus into the input box. When you do that the onscreen keyboard pops up and shifts the top of the ui outside of the remaining viewport instead of adjusting the height of the window to fill the remaining space.

You can see how that can break everything because there is a scrolling div in the middle, so you cannot scroll up to get to the menubar anymore until you scroll the whole middle pre up to the top.

I need this layout to always fill the remaining space on the screen, not shift up when the keyboard appears.

I tried in the Chrome dev tools by emulating th device Nexus 5, and there it seems to work, but when trying to test this on a Samsung S20 in mobile Chrome it doesn't.

Can somebody help to figure out a layout that works responsively with the on screen keyboard on a mobile?

Here is the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cpzqf9vo/1/

Bonus point: is there a way to remove the adressbar from the mobile browser?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023549/get-viewport-height-when-soft-keyboard-is-on)

Comment: There seems to be some interesting developments there. However most are not for all browsers. And the accepted solution doesnt doesnt explain how to detect when the keyboard is on. If you are willing to make an answer here with concrete cross browser solution with code sample it would be very helpful to a wider audience, not only myself.

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute`? Is that an attempt at solving this problem (or another), or is it a requirement of some kind?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74986310/how-to-keep-header-at-top-of-visual-viewport-after-layout-visual-viewport-change/

Comment: Using absolute because I hoped absolute with all left,top,right,bottom at zero would fit the viewport. But the keyboard doesnt care.

Answer (score 2):

To make the header resting at the top while typing on IOS, make your textbox fixed to the bottom and avoid `position:relative;` as much as possible. In your case the CSS should be something similar to this:

```
#commandline {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

CSS fixed bottom is supported by most of the modern mobile browsers (2023):

[image: Browser Compatibility on caniuse for CSS fixed]

The output **before** resolving the issue:

[image: A Screen recorded Demo of the original/unresolved code]

Also in your case, avoiding `position:relative;` helps because it decides the position based on the element's original position. Here is the output **after** resolving the issue:

[image]

Here's the fully fledged code of the solution which has been tested on iPhone 12, 14 Pro Max and 15.

```js
let pre = $("pre")
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    pre.append("<span class='line'>line " + i + "</span>")
}
function bottom() {
    pre.scrollTop(pre.prop("scrollHeight"));
}
$("#commandline").on('keyup', function (e) {
  if(e.which == 13){
    pre.append("<span class='line'>" + $("#commandline").val() + "</span>");
    bottom();
    $("#commandline").val("");
  }
});
bottom();
```

```css
html {
    min-height: 100%;
    
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 4px;
}

#toprow {
    width: 100;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
}

#toprow, #bottomrow {
    flex: none;
    background-color: red;
}

#bottomrow{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

#container {
    flex: 1;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

#commandline {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

pre {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>  <div id="toprow">
        &nbsp;JAYANIKA.COM
      </div>
<div id="container">
   <div id="midrow">
      <pre>
          <span class="line">ton of lines</span>
      </pre> 
   </div>
</div>
      
       <div  id="bottomrow">
        <input type="text" id="commandline">
      </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

For your reference:

[Fix element to bottom of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874141/fix-element-to-bottom-of-screen)

[Why is my position:sticky not working on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54646939/why-is-my-positionsticky-not-working-on-ios)

Comment: On Android Chrome and Safari iPad, when the onscreen keyboard pops up this still pushes the menubar out of screen.

Comment: Just saying android chrome does not make sense, you have to address the specific device

Comment: Does not work on Android (top scrolls out on top and the only way to get back up is to scroll all the lines up top) and has problems even in desktop. The UI is bigger than the viewport and has scroll.

Answer (score 0):

## The Problem

As I can see, you are using a new version of Chrome mobile; that is, Chrome v108+. A few days ago, another guy had a similar problem right here...
[Fixed elements disappear when keyboard opens in Chrome Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77564252/fixed-elements-disappear-when-keyboard-opens-in-chrome-mobile/77564886#77564886)

To make things clear, Google made an announcement, [you can read it here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior/), that this behavior was problematic to many layouts and that a change is coming. This behavior was well-known in Safari browsers, and probably on Chrome for iOS (CriOS). On other mobile browsers (Opera, Firefox, …etc.) your code will work just fine.

## Possible Solutions

In Chrome (Android) you can add the following code to your meta tags...

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

Probably, your code have a viewport meta tag, so you will only need to add `interactive-widget=resizes-content` to the end of it. This way, it will work on the Android version of Chrome. About CriOS or Safari on iOS, I don't actually know a viable solution as I haven't tested any of them. Yet, below are some links that may help you out!

#### Useful Links

https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-changes-coming-in-chrome-108/

https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/

[Is there any fix to iOS, safari and chrome fixed position for when keyboard shows up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200936/is-there-any-fix-to-ios-safari-and-chrome-fixed-position-for-when-keyboard-show)

[Iphone safari not resizing viewport on keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417778/iphone-safari-not-resizing-viewport-on-keyboard-open)

[screen styling when virtual keyboard is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your goal, I did some testing on mobile to see if I could find a solution.

#### VisualViewport API

After lots of research and testing I found that the [VisualViewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport) works the best. Thanks [Mohammed Alkebsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20108229/mohammed-alkebsi) for the reference [Iphone safari not resizing viewport on keyboard open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417778/iphone-safari-not-resizing-viewport-on-keyboard-open). The [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59056851/14802731) from [Matan Hershberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4133353/matan-hershberg) gives reference to the [VisualViewport API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport) on MDN.

##### The Benefits

In your case, the primary benefit of this API, is the `window.visualViewport.height` value. If we use this value on focus of the input, we can always guarantee the correct height to apply to the container. This should be combined with `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` to correct for the misplaced scroll position from the smaller container.

#### Example

###### Quick Note

In this example, I use `user-scalable=no` in the viewport `<meta>` tag, to prevent the automatic zoom-in, mainly because there's no easy way I know of to zoom back out automatically. In most cases you do not want to use this, but it may be applicable in your application.

##### Code

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container'),
  pre = document.querySelector('pre'),
  commandLine = document.querySelector('#commandline')

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  let span = document.createElement('span')
  span.className = 'line'
  span.textContent = 'line ' + i
  pre.appendChild(span)
}

function bottom() {
  pre.scrollTop = pre.scrollHeight
}

commandLine.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.className = 'line'
    span.textContent = commandLine.value
    pre.appendChild(span)
    bottom()
    commandLine.value = ''
  }
})

commandLine.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    container.style.height = window.visualViewport.height

    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, 115)
})

commandLine.addEventListener('blur', function (e) {
  container.style.height = ''
})

bottom()
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#toprow,
#bottomrow {
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}

#midrow {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

pre {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

#commandline {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- optionally include user-scaleable=no to prevent automatic zoom-in on input -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="toprow">MENUBAR</div>
      <div id="midrow">
        <pre>
          <span>ton of lines</span>
        </pre>
      </div>
      <div id="bottomrow">
        <input type="text" id="commandline" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

###### Possible Enhancements

1. You may want to add some additional checks that only run the code in the focus event, if there's a virtual keyboard. This shouldn't be necessary, but it would ensure reliability across devices and browsers, as tablets often have an optional physical keyboard.
2. In this version, I used the `window` for reference. Depending on your use case, you may specify the container instead. I'm not sure how much this would affect it.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help. Thanks for citing me! Really appreciate it.

Comment: There is some trouble when focusing into the input. The input jumps below the bottom of the window... even in the preview of the code snippet.

Comment: @MarinoŠimić Sorry. That was my bad. I'm less familiar with jQuery. It worked great with JavaScript, but my conversion to jQuery isn't 1 to 1. I'm going to switch it to JavaScript, and hopefully that will help more.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working for:

- desktop: chrome, edge, firefox
- android: chrome, firefox, opera, samsung internet
- dont have iOS to test (feedback request)

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
        let pre = $("pre")
        for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            pre.append("<span class='line'>line " + i + "</span>")
        }
        function bottom() {
            pre.scrollTop(pre.prop("scrollHeight"));
        }
        $("#commandline").on('keyup', function (e) {
          if(e.which == 13){
            pre.append("<span class='line'>" + $("#commandline").val() + "</span>");
            bottom();
            $("#commandline").val("");
          }
        });
        bottom();
    });
```

```css
html, body {
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: absolute;
            }

            #toprow {
                background-color: #eee;
                position: relative;
                width:100%;
                color: white;
            }

            #toprow, #bottomrow {
                flex: none;
                background-color: red;
            }

            #midrow {
                flex: 1;
                position: relative;
            }

            #container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom:0;
            }

            .line {
              display: block;
            }

            #commandline {
                border: 1px solid red;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }

            pre {
              overflow-y: scroll;
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              bottom: 0;
              left: 0;
              right: 0;
              margin: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            * {
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
       <div id="toprow">
            MENUBAR
       </div>
       <div id="midrow">
          <pre>
              <span class="line">ton of lines</span>
          </pre> 
       </div>
       <div  id="bottomrow">
        <input type="text" id="commandline">
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This seems to work correctly for the scenarios tested.
Handles the on screen keyboard fine.
I cannot test on IOS, since I dont have one.
If somebody can comment about that it would be helpful.

You would need to save the snippet as an html file and open it on the mobile.

Edit: A collegue tested on iOS and the keyboard opening still pushes the content up instead of resizing it inside the remaining space. If somebody can fix this he can copy my answer, adjust it and I will accept it.

Direct link to page that does not work correctly on iOS but does on android:

https://www.temporasanguinis.it/client/test.html

Comment: A collegue tested on iOS and the keyboard opening still pushes the content up instead of resizing it inside the remaining space. If somebody can fix this he can copy my answer, adjust it and I will accept it.